# CloudFormation: Template error: every Ref object must have a single String value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm attempting to create a CloudFormation stack and am getting the following error:

> A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: every Ref object must have a single String value.

However, when I grep the template looking for `Ref` objects they are all Strings except for a single lookup which looks like

```json
{
  "Ref": {
     "Fn::FindInMap": [
         "InfraMap",
         "SecurityGroups",
         "NATSecurityGroup"
     ]
  }
}
```

The value for this reference is `"NATSecurityGroup": "sg-54e6be30",` which seems OK to me.

Any other thoughts on what this error could be referring to?

Answer (score 16):

```
"Ref": {
     "Fn::FindInMap": [
         "InfraMap",
         "SecurityGroups",
         "NATSecurityGroup"
     ]
}
```

This is not correct, the `Ref` is not required in this case, where the value it is referencing is a constant and not a variable created during the creation of the stack.

Replacing it with

```
"Fn::FindInMap": [
     "InfraMap",
     "SecurityGroups",
     "NATSecurityGroup"
]
```

Resolves the issue.